# Update values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that constantly takes in integer values and outputs the maximum value given so far.

This seems as easy as a simple

```
max a b = maximum [a,b]
```

But the function should "remember" what values were given to it in the past, and compare new values with those as well.

For example: The initial value I want to start with is `-500`. If I call my function with an argument of `5`, then it should return`5`, because 5 is greater than `-500`.

If I then call the function again, this time with an argument of `3`, it should still returns `5`, because even though `3` is greater than `-500`, it is less than `5`.

Is this even possible with side-effect free programming?

Comment: Is it possible to have a side effect in side-effect-free programming? … no. https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad might help.

Comment: But is there a way to do this, without making it as a side effect

Comment: the reasonable answer for a beginner can only be: *no there isn't* - instead make the thing you *remembered* a argument of your function for now (the *state-monad* just make this implicit) - *btw* why do you event want something like it when you can use (in your example) just `maximum` with the list of all things to find the max. element for instead?

Comment: Well, am attempting alpha-beta pruning, so the I need a function that keeps on restricting the alpha and beta bounds. Starting with (-500, 500)

Comment: this is really no problem - just pass your alpha/beta values around (and return the updated versions obviously) - it will even make you understand the algorithm better! - Of course it might get tedious in this case and the state-monad might not be a bad idea after all - but I would recommend it only if you already understand this stuff - if not stick with the explicit arguments/returns for now

Comment: @seedkey Just make alpha and beta arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a direct translation of the alpha-beta [pseudocode.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode) I haven't tested it, but I hope it gets the general method of translating the algorithm across, even if it's not entirely correct.

```
alphaBeta ::
     (state -> Int) -- heuristic
  -> (state -> Bool -> [state]) -- next states
  -> state     
  -> Int   -- depth
  -> Int   -- alpha
  -> Int   -- beta
  -> Bool  -- is max player  
  -> Int   -- score
alphaBeta heu children = go where
  go s d a b p | d == 0 || null ss = heu s
               | otherwise         = score 
    where      
      ss = children s p

      score = fst $ head $ case p of
        True ->
          takeWhile ((<b) . snd) $ scanl step (minBound, a) ss where
            step (v, a) s = (v', max a v') where
              v' = max v (go s (d - 1) a b (not p))
        False ->
          takeWhile ((a<) . snd) $ scanl step (maxBound, b) ss where
            step (v, b) s = (v', min b v') where
              v' = min v (go s (d - 1) a b (not p))
```

We use `scanl` to process each child state of the current state while remembering partial results. We use `takeWhile` to do the cut. Since lists are lazy, we don't process children after the cut. Also, list fusion or garbage collection (depending on optimization levels and GHC version) ensures that `scanl`  uses constant space here. This is a fine example of laziness allowing us to define algorithms compositionally.

Alternatively, we could do the cutting and processing simultaneously, thereby sticking closer to the original presentation. `foldM`  with `Either` lets us process the children one by one and decide at each step whether to stop and return a value with `Left` or continue with `Right`. So we use `Left` as an analogue of the `break` statement in the imperative pseudocode.

```
import Control.Monad

alphaBeta ::
     (state -> Int) -- heuristic
  -> (state -> Bool -> [state]) -- next states
  -> state     
  -> Int   -- depth
  -> Int   -- alpha
  -> Int   -- beta
  -> Bool  -- is max player  
  -> Int   -- score
alphaBeta heu children = go where
  go s d a b p | d == 0 || null ss = heu s
               | otherwise         = score 
    where      
      ss = children s p

      score = either id fst $ case p of
        True ->
          foldM step (minBound, a) ss where
            step (v, a) s | b <= a'   = Left v'
                          | otherwise = Right (v', a')
              where v' = max v (go s (d - 1) a b (not p))
                    a' = max a v'                    
        False ->
          foldM step (maxBound, b) ss where
            step (v, b) s | b' <= a   = Left v'
                          | otherwise = Right (v', b')
              where v' = min v (go s (d - 1) a b (not p))
                    b' = min b v'
```

Comment: That look's interesting, I am just trying to understand scanl, which seems to take a predicament, a value and a list, but in your code it is taking a tuple and a list?

Comment: [`scanl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) is like `foldl` but collects partial results.